# Error 500 when I do two ajax request with Codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm developing an application web with Codeigniter, i have three input `<select>` that depend on each others; the second `<select>` depends of the first, and the third depends of second and the first. I populate these '' with ajax in jQuery.

The first and the second '' work fine, but i have a problem when i populate the third `<select>`. I reviewed in firebug and the response is an Error 500, but the functions are the same that for the second ''.

The Controller's code is:

```
function llenarParroquias() {
    $zona = $this->input->post('zona');
    $decanato = $this->input-post('decanato');

    $this->load->model('Varios_model');
    $parroquias = $this->Varios_model->datosParroquias($zona, $decanato);
    foreach ($parroquias->result() as $parroq)
    {
        $arrParroquias[] = $parroq;
    }
    exit(json_encode($arrParroquias));
}
```

The Ajax's functions are:

```
    function obtenerParroquias(direccion) {
    $('#parroquia').html('');

    var id_zona = $('#vicaria').val();
    var id_decanato = $('#decanato').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: direccion + 'index.php/datos/llenarParroquias/',
        data: { zona: id_zona, decanato: id_decanato },
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(comboParroquias);
}
function comboParroquias(parroqs) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= parroqs.length - 1; i++) {
        $('#parroquia').append('<option value ="' + parroqs[i][0] + '">' + parroqs[i][2] + '</option>');
    }
}
```

I know that my code is not the best, but... Can somebody help me? I have some day with this problem and I can't find the answer...

Thank you in advance.

Regards from México.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After of read each my code's line during some days, I tried change this:

```
$zona = $this->input->post('zona');
$decanato = $this->input-post('decanato');
```

By this:

```
$zona = $_POST['zona'];
$decanato = $_POST['decanato'];
```

And... The Ajax it worked!!! :D

Really I don't understand why this work with `$_POST` and not work with `$this->input->post`, because, in theory, both do the same action.

Well, I answer my question, for anybody that interested it.

Regards from Mexico.